# Toptesi class and sequential page numbering

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering, glossaries, acronyms, roman-numerals

I'm working on a final dissertation and I've been using the ***toptesi*** class provided by our university. The problem is that I wanted to manually add the [glossaries](/questions/tagged/glossaries) package. Now, whilst I managed to insert properly the acronyms list in the right spot (both in the document and the table of contents) by adding this code to the ***toptesi.sty*** file:

```
 \def\acronimi{%
 \iffrontmatter\else\frontmattertrue\fi
 \if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
 \printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
 \pagenumbering{roman}
 \global\@topnum\z@
 \@afterindentfalse
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acronyms}
       }
```

after the default code:

```
\def\frontmatter{\clearpage\ps@plain\pagenumbering{roman}%
    \numeriromanitrue\frontmattertrue\@openrightfalse}
\def\mainmatter{\if@twoside\@openrighttrue\fi
    \clearpage\ps@headings\pagenumbering{arabic}%
    \numeriromanifalse\frontmatterfalse}
\AtBeginDocument{\frontmatter}
\figurespagefalse
\tablespagefalse
\def\sommario{%
 \iffrontmatter\else\frontmattertrue\fi
 \if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
 \global\@topnum\z@
 \@afterindentfalse
 \@schapter{\summaryname}%
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\summaryname}%
        }
\def\ringraziamenti{%
 \iffrontmatter\else\frontmattertrue\fi
 \if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
 \global\@topnum\z@
 \@afterindentfalse
 \@schapter{\acknowledgename}%
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\acknowledgename}%
        }

\renewcommand\chapter{%
  \iffrontmatter\mainmatter\fi
  \if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
  \thispagestyle{plain}%
  \global\@topnum\z@
  \@afterindentfalse
  \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}
\renewcommand\part{%
  \iffrontmatter\mainmatter\fi
  \if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
  \thispagestyle{empty}%
  \if@twocolumn\onecolumn\@tempswatrue\else\@tempswafalse\fi
  \null\vfil
  \secdef\@part\@spart}

\renewcommand\listoffigures{%
    \if@twocolumn\@restonecoltrue\onecolumn\else\@restonecolfalse\fi
    \if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
    \global\@topnum\z@
    \@afterindentfalse
    \@schapter{\listfigurename}
    \@mkboth{\listfigurename}{\listfigurename}%
    \@starttoc{lof}%
    \clearpage
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    }
\renewcommand\listoftables{%
    \if@twocolumn\@restonecoltrue\onecolumn\else\@restonecolfalse\fi
    \if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
    \global\@topnum\z@
    \@afterindentfalse
    \@schapter{\listtablename}%
    \@mkboth{\listtablename}{\listtablename}%
    \@starttoc{lot}%
    \clearpage
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    }  
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
 \if@twocolumn\@restonecoltrue\onecolumn\else\@restonecolfalse\fi
 \if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
 \global\@topnum\z@
 \@afterindentfalse
 \@schapter{\contentsname}%
 \@starttoc{toc}%
 \clearpage
 \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    }
\def\indici{%
 \iffrontmatter\else\frontmattertrue\fi


     \iftablespage
                {\addvspace{10pt}
                \let\saveaddvspace=\addvspace
                \def\addvspace##1{}
                \listoftables
                \let\addvspace=\saveaddvspace}
                \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}%
        \fi
        \iffigurespage
                {\addvspace{10pt}
                \let\saveaddvspace=\addvspace
                \def\addvspace##1{}
                \listoffigures
                \let\addvspace=\saveaddvspace}
                \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}%
        \fi
        \tableofcontents
%          \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Index}%
       }
```

it completely messes up the page numbering. Firstly, the acronyms page numbers are displayed as arabic instead of roman numbers (apart from the last page of the acronyms list which, surprisingly, exhibits a roman number). Secondly, the page numbering sequentiality is lost.

Edit: here is a file package with all the necessary files to simulate this error [Click here to download a working example](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=47958264196854373909)

[image: Table of contents] [image: Passage from acknowledgements to acronyms] [image: Last acronym page with the return of the roman numbers]

Comment: Why setting `\pagenumbering{roman}` in the definition of `\acronimi`? Remove it and the numbering will get back to normal.

Comment: I tried, but as a result all the pages from "acronym" will have an arabic number (whereas I would like roman numbers for the table of contents, acknowledgements, summary and so forth). What changes though is that the sequentiality is, in that case, respected.

Comment: A MWE is needed.

Comment: If by MWE you mean a working example, I've added one in the main thread. Thank you very much for taking interest!

Comment: Sorry, but a 600 KiB zip file is not a MWE.

Comment: I've cleaned the code as much as I could. Now it is a 13KiB zip file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't modify a class file under any circumstances.

Just add the definition of `\acronimi` to your document; here's an example, obtained by reducing your document to a MWE. However you have to remove the `\pagenumbering{roman}` instruction that is the cause of your failure.

There are a few things more to adjust, because `toptesi` tries to do clever things when it finds a `\chapter` command, in particular switching to `\mainmatter`. So we set temporarily `\chapter` to swallow the `*` automatically provided by `glossaries` and to call the internal command `\@schapter`, that is what LaTeX calls when it sees `\chapter*`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,cucitura]{toptesi}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
% we want to teach the correct word for Italian
\addto\captionsitalian{\renewcommand{\acronymname}{Acronimi}}
\makeglossaries

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{%
    pdfpagemode={UseOutlines},
    bookmarksopen,
    pdfstartview={FitH},
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor={blue},
    citecolor={red},
    urlcolor={blue}
  }

\makeatletter
\newcommand\acronimi{%
 \iffrontmatter\else\frontmattertrue\fi
 \if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
 % change the meaning of \chapter in a group
 \begingroup\def\chapter##1{\@schapter}
 \phantomsection % for the hyperlink
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\acronymname} % for the TOC
 \printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
 % The following two lines seem unnecessary
 %\global\@topnum\z@
 %\@afterindentfalse 
 \endgroup
}  
\makeatother

% Define the acronyms
\newacronym{cctv}{CCTV}{closed-circuit television}
\newacronym{cdss}{CDSS}{clinical decision support systems}
\newacronym{chf}{CHF}{chronic heart failure}

\glsaddall

\begin{document}

\sommario

La pressione barometrica di Giove viene misurata
mediante un metodo originale  messo a punto dai candidati, che si basa
sul rilevamento telescopico della pressione.

\ringraziamenti

I candidati ringraziano vivamente il Granduca di Toscana per i mezzi
messi loro a disposizione, ed il signor Von Braun, assistente del
prof.~Albert Einstein, per le informazioni riservate che egli ha
gentilmente fornito loro, e per le utili discussioni che hanno permesso
ai candidati di evitare di riscoprire l'acqua calda.

\acronimi
\indici

\mainmatter

\part{Prima Parte}
\chapter{Introduzione generale}

Le grandezze in gioco ...

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sadly, it's still not working. There must be some problem with the way Latexian launches the makeglossaries command. If I run the makeglossaries command under texmaker, I can see the correct number, but the Acronyms page is not printed. If I use Latexian (and the in-built makeglossaries function) the page is printed but the numbers are wrong again. I'm looking into it. Thank you again.

Comment: @Ales With an unmodified `toptesi` my example works, as the image shows.

Comment: sorry, I didn't mean to say that your example was wrong, I'm sure it does work perfectly. Sadly it doesn't in my computer (with an unmodified `toptesi`. I must be making some mistake while launching the makeglossaries command.

Comment: Nothing. I confirm that the code you posted (copied and pasted) doesn't work (at least on my computer) when I compile using `makeglossaries` on a pristine version of the `toptesi` class (I have deleted the entire texlive2012 distribution and installed the new one, texlive2013). 

If I compile without using the `makeglossaries` command it does show what you posted as an image, but the **Acronimi** page is not compiled properly. I'm puzzled...

Comment: @Ales Now I understand better the problem. A solution is expected soon.

Comment: @Ales It was a bit more difficult than I expected at the beginning; sorry for the previous non working solution; now the problem should be solved.